# Probability of matching

Tags: probability-distributions

Let the alphabet from which characters are taken is of size 'k'

If a string S1 contains 'n' characters

String S2 contains 'm' characters (m << n)

What is the probability of a character in S1 is equal to a character in S2 ?

Comment: It is impossible to say unless you say what alphabet the characters of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are drawn from.  If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are strings over `x`es, for example, then the probability is 1 unless one of the strings is empty.

Comment: What is the number of different characters possible?

Comment: Can S1 or S2 have duplicates? How are S1 and S2 picked with replacement or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the *corresponding* character should be equal: the alphabet contains of $k$ characters, there is for each position a probability of $1/k$ of a match. The probability that there is no match equals $(1-\frac{1}{k})^{\min(m,n)}$, hence the probability of at least one match is $1-(1-\frac{1}{k})^{\min(m,n)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Given an alphabet of $k$ characters, the probability of there being $any$ match between $any$ character in $S1$ and $any$ character in $S2$ given $equal$ probability of each character, is 
$$ 1 - (\frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{k-1} ... \frac{1}{k-m})^n $$

Comment: I think you halfway assumed that $k=26$.

Comment: Ha, yes, but only half way :)